# How to see output of `console.log` when running Jasmine tests

Tags: node.js, jasmine, console.log

I've developed a Node.js module and I'm using Jasmine to write unit tests for it. The module uses `console.log` to print out some information as it executes when called with a `verbose` argument set to true.

Let's say the module looks like this:

***foo.js***

```
function foo(arg1, verbose){
    var output = "Hello " + arg1;
    if(verbose)console.log("Returning %s", output);
    return output;
}
module.exports = foo;
```

Let's say my test looks like this:

***foo-spec.js***

```
const foo = require("path/to/foo")
describe("Foo suite", () => {

    it( "Expect foo to greet", () => {
        expect(foo("World", true)).toBe("Hello World");
    });
});
```

I run my tests by typing `jasmine` in the terminal:

```
$ jasmine
```

Everything works well except I'd like to see the verbose output.

```
$ jasmine
Returning Hello World
```

Is there a way to make Jasmine do this?

Comment: Do you really need to *see* this? Wouldn't it be better in terms of testability to spy on console.log call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I've sort of found a workaround for this. Spying on `console.log` somehow patched it.

***foo-spec.js***

```
const foo = require("path/to/foo")
describe("Foo suite", () => {

    it( "Expect foo to greet", () => {

        //This makes the log visible again from the command line.
        spyOn(console, 'log').and.callThrough();

        expect(foo("World", true)).toBe("Hello World");
    });
});
```

Not sure why, but `spyOn` is making the logs visible again. Even though I'm not really doing anything with it, except invoking `callThrough`. My best guess is that by doing this, `console.log` is actually being called from the Jasmine process.